# Showing that the mapping cone is a chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra

> Let $\alpha \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a morphism of chain complexes. 
>   Let
>   $$
>     d^{C(\alpha)}_n
>   = \begin{bmatrix}
>       -d^{\mathcal{A}}_{n-1}  & 0 \\
>       \phantom{-}\alpha_{n-1} & d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1}
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$ 
>   I want to show that $d^{C(\alpha)}_n \circ d^{C(\alpha)}_{n+1} =0$

\begin{align*}
    d^{C(\alpha)}_n \circ d^{C(\alpha)}_{n+1}
&=  \begin{bmatrix}
      -d^{\mathcal{A}}_{n-1} & 0 \\
      \alpha_{n-1} & d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -d^{\mathcal{A}}_{n} & 0 \\
      \alpha_{n} & d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n}
    \end{bmatrix} \\
&=  \begin{bmatrix}
       -d^{\mathcal{A}}_{n-1} \circ d^{\mathcal{A}}_n
      & 0
      \\
        \alpha_{n-1} \circ -d^{\mathcal{A}}_n
        + d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ \alpha_n
      & d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ d^{\mathcal{D}}_n
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Obviously $-d^{\mathcal{A}}_{n-1} \circ d^{\mathcal{A}}_n = 0$ and $d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ d^{\mathcal{D}}_n = 0$. So we just need to show that $\alpha_{n-1} \circ -d^{\mathcal{A}}_n + d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ \alpha_n = 0$.

We have the following diagram:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    \cdots
    @>>>
    A_{n-1}
    @> d_{n-1}^{\mathcal{A}} > >
    A_n
    @> d_{n}^{\mathcal{A}} >>
    A_{n+1}
    @> d_{n+1}^{\mathcal{A}} >>
    \cdots
    \\
    @.
    @V \alpha_{n-1} VV
    @V \alpha_n VV
    @V \alpha_{n+1} VV
    @.
    \\
    \cdots
    @>>>
    D_{n-1}
    @> d_{n-1}^{\mathcal{D}} > >
    D_n
    @> d_{n}^{\mathcal{D}} >>
    D_{n+1}
    @> d_{n+1}^{\mathcal{D}} >>
    \cdots
  \end{CD}
$$

Let $x \in A_{n}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
   &\, (
           \alpha_{n-1} \circ -d^{\mathcal{A}}_n
         + d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ \alpha_n
       )(a) \\
  =&\,   (\alpha_{n-1} \circ -d^{\mathcal{A}}_n)(a)
       + (d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \circ \alpha_n)(a) \\
  =&\,   \alpha_{n-1}(-d^{\mathcal{A}}_n(a))
       + d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1}(\alpha_n(a)).
\end{align*}

But now I run into a problem. If we look at the diagram, $d^{\mathcal{A}}_n(a) \in A_{n+1}$, but $\alpha_{n-1} \colon A_{n-1} \to D_{n-1}$. So $\alpha_{n-1}(-d^{\mathcal{A}}_n(a))$ does not even make sense, right? We have the same problem for the second term: $\alpha_n(a) \in D_n$ but $d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1} \colon D_{n-1} \to D_n$, so $d^{\mathcal{D}}_{n-1}(\alpha_n(a))$ does not make sense either, right?

So I'm not really sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definition of $d^{C(\alpha)}_n$ is incorrect; only the degrees of $d^A$ and $\alpha$ should be shifted. The correct differential is
$$d^{C(\alpha)}_n = \begin{pmatrix} -d^A_{n-1} & 0 \\ \alpha_{n-1} & d^B_n \end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that this only differs from yours in the $(2,2)$-entry. With this correct differential, we have that
$$d^{C(\alpha)}_n \circ d^{C(\alpha)}_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} d_{n-1}^A \circ d_n^A & 0 \\ -\alpha_{n-1} \circ d_n^A + d_n^B \circ \alpha_n & d_n^B \circ d_{n+1}^B \end{pmatrix}.$$
This is the zero map for the same reason you attempted above: since $\alpha$ is a chain map, we have a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> A_n @>{d^A_n}>> A_{n-1} @>>> \cdots\\
 \ @V{\alpha_n}VV @V{\alpha_{n-1}}VV \ \\
\cdots @>>> B_n @>{d^B_n}>> B_{n-1} @>>> \cdots
\end{CD}$$
Hence the $(2,1)$-entry is the zero map. The other entries are obviously zero maps.